# Diverge? $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n)+ \sin(n^2)=?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I encounter with a problem that is to find:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty, n \in \mathbb{N}} \sin(n)+ \sin(n^2)=?$$
So I do know the set $\{\sin n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ and also knowing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n^2) $ does not converge and it even has infinite limit points. However, I'm running in a trouble that is proving that if $\sin(n)+ \sin(n^2)$ converges, and exists such a subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{N}$,  $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sin(n_k^2) = a$ then: $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \sin(n_k) \neq L - a$$.

Comment: Is the limit here taken over integers or reals? When you say '$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n^2)$' doesn't even have infinite limit points', why do you say that?

Comment: I have just edited for clarification.

Comment: Thank you! What is the source of this problem? At first glance it looks highly non-trivial.

Comment: I am just self-learning about dense set and fascinated that $\sin n$ is dense and $\sin f(n)$ has infinite limit points for $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ so I just wonder what would happen if we add them together.

Comment: Yep it's true. However, my struggle is to prove it rigourously

Comment: That is likely to be a _very_ big struggle; I'm not sure that this is even known rigorously. I suspect you can prove lack of convergence (and probably even density) in the real case without too much trouble just by looking at the right sorts of subsequences, but for the limit through integers it's unclear how to even proceed.

Comment: Note that we can rewrite this as $\lim_n 2\sin(\frac12(n^2+n))\cos(\frac12(n^2-n))$, but without being able to determine the (possible) correlation between these two factors this doesn't really offer much help.

Comment: Yes sir, it's kinda trivial for the real case. Here is a bit troublesome since one has to consider $\pmod{2\pi}$ for $n$ and $n^2$. I suspect that some ways of using Pigeonhole principle can be applied for $(0,1)$ and using $ \vert \sin x - \sin y \vert \geq \vert x-y - \frac{1}{3!} (x^3 - y^3)\vert, x,y \in [0, 2 \pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the results mentioned in [Terence Tao's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/201252/131052) to a related question, there's an easy proof that the limit does not exist.

Pick some suitably large natural number $ N $ and define the random variables $ X(k) = \sin(k) $, $ Y(k) = \sin(k^2) $ on the set of positive integers from $ 0 $ to $ N-1 $ seen as a probability space with the uniform measure. Tao's results say that for "almost all" values of $ N $ (in the sense of natural density, for instance) we have the bounds $ \mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[Y] = o(1) $ as well as $ \mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[Y^2] = 1/2 + o(1) $. (Here I don't mean that the expectations over $ X $ and $ Y $ are equal, just that they are both in the same asymptotic class.) Suppose we pick such an $ N $. In this case, we have that

$$ \mathbb E[(X+Y)^2] = \mathbb E[X^2] + \mathbb E[Y^2] + 2 \mathbb E[XY] = 1 + \frac{2}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \sin(k) \sin(k^2) + o(1) $$

$$ = 1 + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (\cos(k^2 - k) - \cos(k^2 + k)) + o(1) $$

The partial sums of both $ \cos(k^2 - k) $ and $ \cos(k^2 + k) $ are also $ O(\sqrt{N}) $ by the same result of Tao, and so we find that $ \mathbb E[(X+Y)^2] = 1 + o(1) $ for most values of $ N $. On the other hand, we also know that $ \mathbb E[X+Y] = o(1) $ for most values of $ N $. No convergent sequence can have both of these properties at once, so we conclude that $ \sin(n) + \sin(n^2) $ does not converge.

Comment: The approach is truly interesting sir. However, the point is that I don't have a strong background in probability theory to begin with in order to understand your argument. And also the problem would probably at Undergrad math level so there would be an "elementary" way I suppose.

Comment: @NguyễnQuân You said you'd come up with this problem yourself — there are a _lot_ of problems that can be posed using undergraduate terminology but not solved by it.

Comment: @NguyễnQuân here's a great example of an undergrad-looking problem whose solution, if found, will likely make use of non-undergrad methods: "Prove or disprove that the Flint-Hills series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\sin^2(n)}$ converges."

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Fermat‘s last Theorem can be stated easily using only first semester terminology.